# Creating a dataframe from a csv file in pandas: column issue

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, spyder

I have a messy text file that I need to sort into columns in a dataframe so I 
can do the data analysis I need to do. Here is the messy looking file: 
[Messy text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM60x.png)

I can read it in as a csv file, that looks a bit nicer using:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('phx_30kV_indepth_0_0_outfile.txt')
print(data)
```

And this prints out the data aligned, but the issue is that the output is [640 rows x 1 column]. And I need to separate it into multiple columns and manipulate it as a dataframe.

I have tried a number of solutions using StringIO that have worked here before, but nothing seems to be doing the trick.

However, when I do this, there is the issue that the

Comment: You can figure this out by reading the documentation for read_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
Passing `sep=' '` to the `read_csv` method might do the trick.

Comment: I have in fact already checked the documentation.  What I am trying to do is create a dataframe, not a csv file, so that I can manipulate the data. I apologize the image is not readable, this is one of my first questions, and stack will not let me upload an actual image.

Answer (score 1):

#### [**`delim_whitespace=True`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Link to docs ^

```
df = pd.read_csv('phx_30kV_indepth_0_0_outfile.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input file is actually not in **CSV** format.

As you provided only *.png* picture, it is even not clear, whether this file
is divided into rows or not.

If not, you have to start from "cutting" the content into individual lines and
read the content from the output file - result of this cutting.

I think, this is the first step, before you can use either `read_csv` or `read_table` (of course, with `delim_whitespace=True`).